# Drupal comments per fields

Tags: drupal, cck

I have been looking all over for this, but so far without any luck. Is there a way to have comments per field instead of per node in drupal? If there are no modules available for this, do you think it would be hard to implement?

I thought I could make a "pseudo-content-type" with views that's nothing more than several content types displayed one on top of the other, so you could comment any of them. But then I don't know a way of making the user create all those content types at once.

Comment: Perhaps if you give more info about why you are trying to collect comments per field we can give you some ideas.

Comment: The site is for students creating video documentaries. The content type has different fields describing different aspects of documentary creation: what are they going to do, how they intend to do it, what techniques are going to be used, etc. It would be good if the teachers and other interested people could comment on each aspect individually.

Answer (score 1):

The built-in comment module is not going to do comments per field on a node. I've been drupaling for almost three years and I don't know of any module that allows comments per field.

It is possible to do, but it would take a custom module and plenty of slick programming to get it to work. As far as difficulty I think an intermediate PHP developer with some knowledge of Drupal should be able to whip this out.

Answer (score 0):

A kind of quick solution would be using [panel module](http://drupal.org/project/panels); form all your commentable content in nodes ad put them together all into a panel. This is kind a quick and static solution, possibly with views one can make it more custom.